# How to import an external library into a ReactJS Application (Locally)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, materialize

I've a ReactJS application, and I'm using MaterializeCSS through react-materialize. I've installed react-materialized and added the references to MaterializeCSS files in my index.html file, as ordered:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
(...)
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

It's working fine, but I will spend 10 days in a place with no internet, and I'd like to develop my project there, so the CDN hosted file won't work. So I'm trying to host materialize files in my own project.

I've managed to do that with css files, copied it to a folder in my project structure and imported in App.js:

```
import './resources/materialize/css/materialize.css';
```

But when I tried to do the same with .js file, I get tons of errors, since it's trying to transpile materialize.js files.

Where should I put this file and how can I reference it from my project?

Comment: Download the file from the CDN, put it in your `public` folder and link to it in `index.html`

Comment: @ChrisG You should write your comment as an answer, so I can accept it. It was the simpliest but solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install it via npm using windows command prompt, simply Start > Run > cmd,
locate your project folder via `cd <foldername>` and type this:

```
npm install --save materialize-css@next
```

and at your **Index.js**: - which is in the root folder of your application

```
import 'materialize-css';
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
```

I also strongly recommend material UI which is very convenient with react applications: https://material-ui.com/

Comment: Then how do I import it in my project? Or it's done automatically?

Comment: just add `import 'materialize-css'` at the start of your component

Comment: I've done that with the CSS file , and its working, even just downloading and copying the files. My problem is with the .JS file.

Comment: Add it to your base page, usually "index.js"

Comment: @ChrisG comment in the question solved my problem, but I'll take a look at material-ui, which seems interesting. Since I'm at the beginning of my project, I could make that change.

Comment: take a shot, I always use Material UI for web projects, you can override styles and use grid system they provide for responsive design

Comment: Is there a easy way to change primay color? The one used in navbar and buttons?

Comment: you mean in material ui? or generally in css ?

Comment: in material-ui. I'd like to make the color of my app customizable. But I find I sample app on their site that does that. I'll take a look.

Comment: You can do it by setting a theme and adding primary, secondary etc palette, take a look: https://github.com/Oner-T/social_media_app-client/blob/master/src/util/theme.js

Comment: @Marlon btw Chris's answer is ok, but it is not a good practice to download to the public folder or using CDN. npm install and import/export are better solutions, as a beginner, get used to it imho.

Comment: `materialize` doesn't have a module version; it can be installed but not imported into a webpack project. So good practice or not, it very much depends on whether the package is an actual ES6 module or not. Installing it is fine in general but OP then has to move the file from `dist` to `public` anyway, so what's the point?

Comment: @ChrisG I did not know that and it is good to know from your explanation. I just said that it is a good practice to install and import modules. Wheather Materialize-css is a module or not, still my statement is valid. It was not personal so you can calm down and also you didn't need to downvote my answer. I am here just to learn new stuff and share my knowledge,I learned from you and thank you for that.

Comment: How is a statement "valid" if the core assertion is wrong? Good practice first and foremost is to not do something that doesn't make sense, and since using materialize requires a static link in index html, installing it is pointless. (Notice the calmness of my statement, btw) I don't think _I'm_ the one taking things personal here.

Answer (score 0):

you can run

```
npm install --save materialize-css@next
```

and then you can add it in the index.js file the following import:

```
import 'materialize-css'; //This adds the Js file
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
```

Comment: The CSS file are ok, my problem is with the .JS file.

Comment: The js file should be included just by adding: 
    import M from 'materialize-css'

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution, to avoid potentially complex webpack setups is to temporarly download the actual files from their website:

https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html

And just place their file in your js folder and reference it via script tag, exactly as they show in their "Setup - Project Structure" section.

I know it's not the most elegant solution but it might work if you are in a rush, otherwise you need to look how to include the project with webpack without it touching its code.